# Solving Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Do I solve this using Bernoulli? I don't seem to reach to the solution. Please help

$$2x^2y-x^3y'=y^3$$

I rewrote it as $$y'-2\frac{y}{x}=-\frac{y^3}{x^3}$$
Now I made the substitution $\frac{y}{x}=v$
Why is not this working?

Comment: Fyi, this is called a Homogeneous Equation (an overloaded term). Your substitution will work.

Comment: Show us your result of the substitution.

Answer (score 3):

Using your substitution, $y = xv \Rightarrow y' = v + xv'$. Thus the equation can be rewritten as

$$(xv' + v) - 2v = -v^3$$

This is separable. Solve for $v$ and hence $y$.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$y = v x \implies y' = v + x v'$$

Substituting into the original DE, we get:

$$v + x v' - 2 v = -v^3$$

This is a separable equation and we get:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dv}{v - v^3} = \int \dfrac{dx}{x}$$

This leads to:

$$v(x) = \pm \dfrac{c_1 x}{\sqrt{c_1 x^2 + 1}}$$

Now use $$v = \dfrac yx$$

Note: Another reduction was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also treat this as a Bernoulli equation and set $t=y^{1-3}=y^{-2}$, so $t'=-2y^{-3}y'$. The equation becomes linear in $t$, with
$$\frac{1}{2}x^3t'+2x^2t=1$$